# Unable to use multiple not in Statements

Tags: mysql, exists, notin

I am looking to find entries that do not exist within the Practice and Game table however I am unable to use a second not in statement. Is there any other way to do this?

```
 select VenueID from Venue
 where VenueID not in (select VenueID from Practice)
 and not in (select VenueId from Game)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the `NOT IN` statement, including the column name:

```
SELECT VenueID
FROM Venue
WHERE VenueID NOT IN (SELECT VenueID FROM Practice) AND
      VenueID NOT IN (SELECT VenueId FROM Game)
       ^^^ you omitted the second column name
```

One alternative to using `NOT IN` would be to do two left joins:

```
SELECT VenueID
FROM Venue t1
LEFT JOIN Practice t2
    ON t1.VenueID = t2.VenueID
LEFT JOIN Game t3
    ON t1.VenueID = t3.VenueID
WHERE t2.VenueID IS NULL AND
      t3.VenueID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the column name in the second `not in` (each criterion is separate and the syntax is *<column> NOT IN <value set>*):

```
select VenueID from Venue
where VenueID not in (select VenueID from Practice)
and VenueID not in (select VenueId from Game)
--  ^^^^^^^
```